# Killing a specific process in a pipeline, from later in the pipeline

Tags: shell, process, telnet

I'm writing a shell script that uses `telnet` to connect to a server, send a query, and then grab the one-line response for further processing. The classic solution is to set up a subshell which `echo`s the query and then runs `sleep` to keep the connection open long enough for the response to be returned:

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVER_ADD=localhost
SERVER_PORT=9995

result=$( ( echo '{"op":"get","path":"access"}'; sleep 30 ) | telnet "$SERVER_ADD" "$SERVER_PORT" )
    
echo "$result"
```

This works, except that the `sleep` has to be longer than the longest the server might take to respond. This means that every invocation will take that long, which pushes the minimum time out from tens of milliseconds to tens of seconds. I need my script to wait for that first line of response, and then terminate the process so it can go on to do other things.

(Yes: I know the obvious answer is "use [`expect`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index)." Unfortunately, I'm targeting an embedded system, and adding `expect` and the [`TcL`](https://tcl-lang.org/) script engine that it is written in would add about a megabyte to my image size. No can do.)

After much trial and error, I came up with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVER_ADD=localhost
SERVER_PORT=9995

result=$( ( echo '{"op":"get","path":"access"}'; sleep 30 ) |
    telnet "$SERVER_ADD" "$SERVER_PORT" |
    while read -r line; do
        echo "$line"
        killall sleep
    done ) 2>/dev/null
echo "$result"
```

Explanation

- Set up a subshell that echoes the query and then sleeps long enough for the longest response time
- Pipe to `telnet` to make the connection
- Pipe the server response to a loop, one line at a time
- Once the first line has been captured and echoed, kill the `sleep` command by name, which ends the subshell and thus the telnet connection
- The `2>/dev/null` consumes the "Terminated" message that the `sleep` command prints when it is terminated

This works well, EXCEPT for that `killall sleep`. This will kill EVERY instance of `sleep` under this user's control. Most times this won't be a problem, but the other times it will be a **seriously** confusing source of bugs.

How can I kill that `sleep` (or the entire subshell) when needed, without collateral damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a fifo to send data to the telnet, so you can close it at the wanted time.

```sh
rm -f myfifo
mkfifo myfifo
result=$(
    telnet "$SERVER_ADD" "$SERVER_PORT"  <myfifo  |
    (  echo '{"op":"get","path":"access"}'  >&5
       while read -r line; do
          echo "$line"
          exec 5>&-
       done
    ) 5>myfifo
)
```

The syntax `5>myfifo` (no space) opens a new output file description number 5 writing to the fifo. The `echo >&5` writes to this fd. The `exec 5>&-` closes this fd. This syntax should work in `ash`.

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. Still working on it, but any hints would be helpful. (Yowza: every answer teaches me something. Thanks.)

Comment: I left a `)` in the wrong place, sorry. Telnet is a tricky protocol. Not all servers react the same as to when they start reading input, when they disconnect or notice a disconnect.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `bash` you could try a coprocess instead:

```sh
coproc telnet "$SERVER_ADD" "$SERVER_PORT" 
echo '{"op":"get","path":"access"}' >&${COPROC[1]}
result=
while IFS= read -r line
do    result+="$line
"
done <&${COPROC[0]}
```

The `coproc` bash command launches a process, and creates an array named `COPROC` holding two file descriptors, stdin and stdout of the process.
You can then write and read them at will.
If your telnet doesn't end after one command you may need to send a second command (eg `echo 'exit' >&${COPROC[1]}`) to break the connection.

Comment: Very cool; I hadn't seen "coproc" before. Unfortunately, I don't have bash (it's busybox's version of ash), and it doesn't have coproc.

Answer (score 2):

You could try replacing the sleep by a `flock` command on an arbitrary file whilst running telnet. A second `flock` in place of the sleep will then hang. A third `flock -u` can release the lock at any time.

Though typical usage is `flock lockfile command`, this script exploits the usage `flock filedescriptor`. This is because `flock -u` can only be used on a file descriptor, and without a command (adding a command forces the file descriptor arg to be taken as a filename).

By opening the lockfile just once, and assigning it file descriptor 5 (arbitrarily), `flock 5` will lock it, and `flock -u 5` will unlock it.

```sh
result=$(
    exec 5>mylock
    flock 5
    ( echo '{"op":"get","path":"access"}'; flock mylock true ) |
    telnet "$SERVER_ADD" "$SERVER_PORT" |
    while read line; do
        echo "$line"
        flock -u 5
    done 
) 2>/dev/null
```

See this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67351646/5008284) for a simple test of `flock -u`.

Comment: I still can't get this version to work. But, your description of the use of `flock` with file descriptors would be a great answer to my ["What does `flock -u` actually do?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351646/what-does-flock-u-actually-do) that I asked after this; happy to upvote/accept it as an answer.

Comment: I've revived and modified this answer for completeness now we have a working example of how to use an lock file by name and fd with `-u`.

Comment: Primo: now that works, too. Of your two non-coproc-related questions, which do you think is the best answer?

Comment: The best answer is always the one that is easiest to write, understand, and maintain, so for me the fifo is the one to keep.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks for all the help.