# What does `flock -u` actually do?

Tags: shell, locking, flock

I'm playing around with the command `flock`, which obtains and releases locks on files. For example, if I run

```
flock /tmp/mylock true
```

then it immediately exits, presumably obtaining and then releasing the lock. If I run

```
flock /tmp/mylock sleep 100
```

then it delays 100 seconds, again obtaining and releasing the lock. And, if I run the following in two separate shells:

```
flock /tmp/mylock sleep 100
```

and

```
flock /tmp/mylock true
```

then the second command is blocked, because it can't obtain the lock while the first command runs. Once the `sleep 100` completes and the lock is released, the second command runs and exits. All good.

Here's the problem. If, during that 100 second delay, I run the following in a third shell:

```
flock -u /tmp/mylock true
```

then what happens? The man page for flock says:

```
   -u, --unlock
          Drop  a  lock.   This  is  usually not required, since a lock is
          automatically dropped when the file is closed.  However, it  may
          be  required  in special cases, for example if the enclosed com-
          mand group may have forked a background process which should not
          be holding the lock.
```

So, this should drop the lock, which should allow `flock /tmp/mylock true` to run, right? (I would also guess that the `flock /tmp/mylock sleep 100` would immediately exit, but that's speculation.)

What happens? Nothing. `flock -u /tmp/mylock true` immediately exits, but `flock /tmp/mylock true` continues to be blocked, and `flock /tmp/mylock sleep 100` continues to exit.

What does `flock -u /tmp/mylock <command>` actually do?

(All examples tested on Ubuntu 18.04.)

Comment: I suspect it's meant to be used with file descriptor numbers, not filenames.

Comment: If that's true (and you have an example) it would be a good answer.

Comment: Well, considering how file locking works, it's the only thing that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with `-u` working with file descriptor 9 open on a file `mylock`, successfully unlocking 9 so that a backgrounded `flock mylock` can proceed.
Note that `flock 9` cannot also have a command as in that case the "9" is taken to be a filename, not an fd.

```sh
bash -s <<\!  9>mylock 2>&1 |
 flock 9; echo gotlock1
 flock 9; echo gotlock2
 9>&- flock mylock bash -c 'echo start_sleep;sleep 8; echo end_sleep' &  
 sleep 2
 flock -u 9; echo unlock; sleep .1
 flock 9; echo gotlock3
!

awk '{t2=systime(); if(t1==0)t1=t2; printf "%2d %s\n",t2-t1,$0; t1=t2}'
```

The first line makes bash run the following lines after opening fd 9, but also pipes stdout and stderr through the awk script seen at the end. This is just to annotate the output with the timing of the lines. The result is:

```
 0 gotlock1
 0 gotlock2
 2 unlock
 0 start_sleep
 8 end_sleep
 0 gotlock3
```

This shows the first 2 `flock 9` commands run immediately. Then a `flock mylock` command is run in the background, after closing fd 9 just for this line. This command could have been run from a second window, for example. The output shows that it hangs, as we do not see `start_sleep`. This means that the preceding `flock 9` did actually get an exclusive lock.

The output then shows that after `sleep 2` and `flock -u 9` we get the `unlock` echo, and only then does the background command get the lock and starts its `sleep 8`.

The main script immediately does a `flock 9`, but the output shows that this does not proceed until the background script ends with `end_sleep` 8 seconds later, and the main script outputs `gotlock3`.

The `lslocks` command sometimes shows 2 processes interested in the lock. The `*` means a wait:

```
COMMAND           PID  TYPE SIZE MODE  M      START        END PATH
flock           23671 FLOCK   0B WRITE* 0          0          0 /tmp/mylock
flock           23655 FLOCK   0B WRITE  0          0          0 /tmp/mylock
```

But it does not show the result of the first `flock 9` on its own, presumably because there is no process with the lock, even though the file truly is locked, as we see when the background job cannot proceed.